# how to use To Sphere, Shear, Bend, Push/Pull operations in Object mode

Tags: interface, object-mode

can someone explain to me what or how to use To Sphere, Shear, Bend, and Push/Pull operations in Object mode in the blender they don't seem to do anything in Object mode so why are they there?

Comment: Push/Pull certainly works in Object mode. You do have to have more than one object selected of course. Bend works too although I've never found a use for it. No idea about the others. I never use them.

Answer (score 3):

It works if you select several objects, each one will work as a single vertex, example with the *Shear* operation in *Object* mode:

[image]